# Magento 1.9.3: every product is displayed in the search in full text mode

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch, ce-1.9.3.0

When searching for a product in 1.9.3, every product comes up in the list in fulltext mode.

How do I fix that issue ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit: this is not the only 1.9.3.0 bug. See this answer for details and a module that fixes all the bugs: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140826/2380

This is a bug.

Thanks to IWeb for developping the fix available here: https://gist.github.com/balloz/d526e7dbe14c295d706be748e294c8a4

So here's the steps to take to fix the bug:

First, copy `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php`

Then do the following:

Replace line 132:

```
$this->getSelect()->orWhere('FALSE');
```

With:

```
$this->getSelect()->where('FALSE');
```

Then copy `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php`

And do the following:

**After this code line 350**:

```
if ($like) {
    $likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
}
```

You need to **add a closing bracket** by adding:

```
}
```

Then **after this code line 383**:

```
$this->_foundData = $adapter->fetchPairs($select, $bind);
```

You need to **remove the closing bracket**:

```
}
```

Edit: thanks to Jacques from Monsieur Biz here's a "clean" patch (which creates automatically the fixed file under `app/code/local` : https://gist.github.com/jacquesbh/c6283faab001d724806c1639a821ff7c

NB: be careful if you ever applied the AND operator this the resource model (as described here: http://markustenghamn.com/improve-search-function-magento), the patch may fail and/or you may have to reapply the AND operator description)