# Error when running full text search in Magento 1.9.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.3.0, fulltext

I was installing some e-commerce tagging for a customer (`cart.phtml` and `view.phtml`) and after doing some regression testing it was found that the full-text search function was not working. This function was not tested prior to work commencing so it is not clear whether I can rule out my changes at this time.

The error that is being reported is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method 
>   Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::getFoundData() 
>   in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php on line 148

I definitely didn't touch this script at all, but one thing I didn't do was a test if the search was working in the first place.  The relevant source code from this script is:

```
public function getFoundIds()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_foundData)) {
            /** @var Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext $preparedResult */
            $preparedResult = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/fulltext');
            $preparedResult->prepareResult();
            $this->_foundData = $preparedResult->getResource()->getFoundData();
        }
        if (isset($this->_orders[self::RELEVANCE_ORDER_NAME])) {
            $this->_resortFoundDataByRelevance();
        }
        return array_keys($this->_foundData);
    }
```

Searching for errors relating to this class and `getFoundData()` have not been fruitful.

This does not appear to be the same issue as [Magento 1.9.3: every product is displayed in the search in full text mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140707/magento-1-9-3-every-product-is-displayed-in-the-search-in-full-text-mode) as I am not seeing any search results.

Comment: Are you running 1.9.3.0 ?

Comment: Yes: Magento ver. 1.9.3.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.9.3: every product is displayed in the search in full text mode](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140707/magento-1-9-3-every-product-is-displayed-in-the-search-in-full-text-mode)

Comment: On top of that there's several bugs on 1.9.3 I suggest you check that out: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140826/2380

Comment: Did you upgrade to 1.9.3  or did you original started on 1.9.3?

Comment: It was on 1.9.3 when I started.

Comment: I have the same Problem

Comment: https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the show but maybe this can help others.
We had the same error after our 1.9.2.4 -> 1.9.3.3 upgrade.  This is a call to the getFoundData method within Fulltext.php.  We happened to have a custom version of Fulltext.php in our /local code base which was based on 1.9.2.4.  This custom version does not contain the getFoundData method.  Removed the /local version and the search works fine.  Now trying to figure out why we needed a custom version in the first place!

Comment: Thanks, this was the exact issue we had as well on a migrated site that we upgraded. The store's reason for running a local Fulltext.php was for a hack to match keywords with "AND" instead of "OR" conditions