# Search in Magento 1.9.3.4 does not work

Tags: magento1.9.3

I have problem with search in Magento 1.9.3.4. It does not return any results (I do not receive errors, neither in logs, nor on site). I have tried solutions suggested in threads linked below question however nothing changed. I have clean install of Magento on server where everything normally works. We tried to reindex and do rollback on older versions of CatalogSearch (after each change reindex). Products are set to visible in both catalog and search. Caches are all off. Any ideas please?

[Magento Search returns no product after 1.9.3.1 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146645/magento-search-returns-no-product-after-1-9-3-1-upgrade)
[Magento 1.9.3: every product is displayed in the search in full text mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140707/magento-1-9-3-every-product-is-displayed-in-the-search-in-full-text-mode/140708#140708)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried these tips? https://magently.com/blog/what-to-do-when-your-search-returns-no-results/

Fix should help it

Comment: Well i guess it helped. According to boss i had to reindex only search index. After applying things in this article i got angry and reindexed everything. And voila, it works!