# Search not working any more with Magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch, bug

Unfortunately research no longer gives any matches with Magento 1.9.3.1, what could be the reason? are there known bugs?
example here: http://test.arredomobilionline.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?q=tavolo

I've reindexed, cleared cache and attribute name is enabled for research.

Comment: May be ReIndexing from admin will help you

Comment: reindexing will works

Comment: reindex didn't work sorry...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to reindexing?

1. if that can't help you, delete your `result.phtml` on `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch`
2. Then, replace your `result.phtml` with the `result.phtml` from magento 1.9.3.1 default.

Comment: just tried that, reindexed and cleared cache but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these step to check issue :

1. Check the product `visibility` and set as `catalog search`
2. Check the attribute setting like name, detail etc... and set it to `Use in quick search` to `yes`.
3. Flush all cache.
4. Reindex all after these step.

Comment: already done and nothing

Comment: Try this solution : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140707/magento-1-9-3-every-product-is-displayed-in-the-search-in-full-text-mode

Comment: I've checked inside the file but I don't have $this->getSelect()->orWhere('FALSE'); like this so I don't know how to appy the fix...

Comment: It's exactly $this->getSelect()->where('FALSE'); already...